# Angularjs + Firebase - creating a separate edit view

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I'm using Firebase which has worked great and I'm able to create, view/list, and edit data in place in a single view.

I'd like to add a separate view that shows the details of the data selected in the list view and allows the user to edit the details.

I've been able to get the detail page to show the details of the item selected using $routeParams but I've been unable to figure out out to edit the data and have it submitted back to Firebase so the record is updated.

Are there any examples of a similar multi page angularjs application I can refer to, I've looked but haven't had any luck.

Comment: Can you share a minimal code sample that reproduces your problem? Without that it's pretty tricky to help you overcome the obstacle.

Comment: Note that recommendations for off-site resources are off topic for Stack Overflow. We'd rather get the pertinent information on SO itself.